# Using a Character Mesh as a Fluid Obstacle

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm trying to use an imported character mesh as a fluid obstacle. The only way I can get it to actually act as an obstacle is to select "Export Animated Mesh" in the fluid obstacle settings. (Selecting shell or volume or both produces no interaction.) However with that enabled, I lose the ability to set slip settings and the fluid ends up "sticking" to the model. Is there any way around this?